# Dynamic results from query builder

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am working on a search filter atm where people can specify things like (example) size, color, fabric and so on.

Obviously I have models for each i.e. size, color and fabric. But since this "search" should return every result i.e. size + color + fabric and not just one of the three I would need to make a new struct which contains all the (size, color and fabric) to be able to consume the result that Gorm would return.

Since we have a LOT of filters, this could get very messy. Does anyone know if there is a better way to do it? or what would be a best practice to do this?

```
type Result struct {
  ID   int
  Name string
  Age  int
}

var result Result
db.Raw("SELECT id, name, age FROM users WHERE name = ?", 3).Scan(&result)
```

The above example illustrates how I think it should be done, but as you can expect with the amount of data I need to return this struct would become huge.

The results are quite large in terms of data. I mean what I would want in return in the final version for example (this is about sales):

What products were bought, the amount, color and size. Payment data i.e. price, tax, payment method. Customer information, et cetera.

So in total there is a lot of information to store.

All this information should be returned as a JSON format so we can call it through an API call.

Each call should give back 100 up to 15.000 results, to give you an idea of the side of the data.

Hope someone can explain a bit about a best practice method and -or how I should solve this problem as I am unsure on how to code this effectively.

Comment: Have you tried using the `map[string]interface{}` as `result`? It might work if it is only one record that you are querying.

Comment: Clarifying questions: what entify does each result row represent? Can the results of your search be multiple different entities with different schemas? You say you have models of each of size, color, fabric, are each of these stored in different tables?